# how to hydrate a javascript object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a javascript object (userObject) that i populate on one page, then i add the object into the localstorage using the JSON.stringify

Now on the next page, i would like to rehydrate a userObject with the values from the localStorage on the first page.

the userObject global variable is declared once, in the shared/common javascript.

but using the current logic, the login page stores username and userid in the userObject, then a window.location.href does the page redirection. This is where the data in the userObject is being cleared (assuming the old object is being washed away, in favor of a new object on the new page).

the question is, how do i rehydrate the new userObject on the main page with the values from the localStorage.

Here is how an i loading the locastorage

```
localStorage.setItem('userObject', JSON.stringify(userObject));
```

this is what i was thinking on rehydrating the userObject

```
userObject = localStorage.getItem('userObject');
```

but upon viewing the userObject...  it is just a string or values, it doesn't recreate the object and fill the values, its just a long string...

Comment: JSON.parse(localstorage.key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localstorage can't know how was the original object. You need to explicitly call JSON.parse().

```
userObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userObject'));
```

**UPDATE**:

Note that functions are never serialized or supported in JSON. This is because it would not be reliable to reconstruct functions or prototypes from a generated "source code", because a) prototypes aren't captured in JSON and b) functions may have access to closures.

In order to have methods on rehydrated object prototype, proceed thisway:

```js
// User constructor function
function User() {

}

User.prototype.isValid = function () {
  return true;
};

User.prototype.isAdmin = function () {
  return this.name === "admin";
};

// create and serialize an object
var userA = new User();
userA.name = "admin";

var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userA));

// rehydrate with functions on prototype
var userB = new User();
for (var prop in copy) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(copy, prop)) {
    userB[prop] = copy[prop];
  }
}

console.log(userB.isAdmin());
```

Comment: additional note: the functions are not being moved between the serialize and rehydration.   any ideas on how to bring the functions into the hydration process?

Comment: functions are never serialized, and you can't just reconstruct a function from its source code, because it may have access to some closure.

Comment: one approch would be newing an object that has that functions on the prototype, then copy over all properties from rehydrated object.